# Android Lazy Loading

Tags: android

I have implemented concept of lazy loading in my project, and I'm showing an image through URL in List view through lazy loading. All are working absolutely fine.

But now problem is I want to pass the image from one screen to another which is downloaded from URL.

I'm not able to do that. For your reference, I'm pasting the code:

```
package com.android.istock;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    //the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private File cacheDir;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        if(cache.containsKey(url))
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale++;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        if(((String)photoToLoad.imageView.getTag()).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //clear memory cache
        cache.clear();

        //clear SD cache
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

Now I want to use the image in next screen. How can I do that?

Comment: I think I saw this code here before, with Apache copyright. It is from LauncherPro if I remember right.

Answer (score 1):

You have used a function getBitmap.

"private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)"

This function returns you the image that are cached in  SDCard.
See line
"  //from SD cache  "
It identifies the image by it's hashcode.
Now since images are cached, you can use the similar code of the getBitmap, just you have to pass URL to that page where you want to access it, set some variables like cacheDir etc. 

Hope this will be some help.